# error connectingError: connect ECONNREFUSED <my IP>

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I'm receiving an error when trying to connect to mysql server on google cloud. My connection code is as follows:
The part that says  is my actual IP address and the part that says  is my actual password that I have added to google cloud sql. Both have been removed for the post. I am able to connect on mysql workbench but unable to on my node.js program.

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"<my IP>",
    user:"root",
    password: "<password>",
    database: 'walkinschema'
});
```

The code above is from my db.js file that is used to connect to the database and my index.js code is as follows:

```
const con = require("../test/db.js");
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get("/", function(req, res, next){
    var query = "SELECT * FROM walkintable";
    con.query(query, function(err, data){
        if(error){
            throw error;
        }
        else{
            res.render('sample_data', {
                title: 'Node.js MySQL', 
                action: 'list',
                sampleData: data
            })
            res.send({ "name": "GeeksforGeeks" });
        }
    })
})
app.listen(PORT, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(`listening to port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

I am simply trying to connect to the server and not worried about anything else at the moment. I tried finding other issues on stack and gitHub but all the options I tried did not work.